# JAVA: SQLite get last inserted row ID

Tags: java, sqlite

So I know this is a commonly asked question (I've been looking into this for a while now), however, I've been having some issues. I'm inserting a piece of data into my SQLite database, and then I want to retrieve the ID of that newly inserted row. I have a 'globalId' column which is an auto incrementing integer. I've tried many things such as using last_insert_rowid(), getting the max id in the database after inserting it, but neither seem to work.

DBConnection.sql.modifyQuery("INSERT INTO pp_data (...) VALUES (...)");

is my modifyQuery, I've replaced all the actual data with ... because there's a lot of stuff.
I then have a readQuery method which will return a ResultSet, and with that, I need to get the column Id.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried: `SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY column DESC LIMIT 1;`

Comment: Yeah I did, that wasn't working properly either